# Read a text file, identify a pattern and replace its value with Tcl

Tags: regex, file, tcl

I'm interested in a tcl procedure that reads a text file, identifies a pattern and replaces a value of that pattern . 
Assuming the , "data" is the needed pattern , and the current value is 1 2 3, how can I update the value for each "data" instance to value 3 2 1? I had several attempts with `fileutil` package , yet I didn't managed to replace the values . 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please show what you have so far. You should also look at the documentation one more time: the operations you are looking for aren't exactly hidden.

Comment: I use the following code structure:                                                         package require fileutil
set pattern {data}

set filename test.txt

proc processContents {fileContents} {
 return [string map {(1 2 3) {3 2 1}}] $fileContents
 }
fileutil::updateInPlace test.txt processContents                                                      I'm not very experienced with tcl, so I'm not sure what to look for in the documentation

Comment: Why the downvotes? It's a useful question, and the OP had made an honest attempt to solve the problem him-/herself. It would be better if someone with editing rights would copy the code into the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `fileutil` for this task, Tcl core commands will do. But let's work with `fileutil`.

Your code was

```
package require fileutil

set pattern {data}
set filename test.txt

proc processContents {fileContents} {
    return [string map {(1 2 3) {3 2 1}}] $fileContents
}

fileutil::updateInPlace test.txt processContents
```

That is a fair start, but doesn't work for a couple of reasons.

One problem is that the ending bracket of the argument to `return` should be to the right of `$fileContents`, not to the left of it.

The other problem is that the list of substitutions provided to `string map` *doesn't* say "replace (1 2 3) with 3 2 1", it says "replace (1 with 2 and 3) with 3 2 1". This is because the open and close round brackets, or parentheses if you are American, don't have any syntactic significance here, they're just text. The unquoted spaces around the 2 means that this bit of text is three list elements, not one. To make `(1 2 3)` a single list element, you need to quote the spaces, like in one of these:

```
(1\ 2\ 3)
"(1 2 3)"
{(1 2 3)}
```

I suspect you didn't want to have the parentheses anyway, so the line should be:

```
    return [string map {{1 2 3} {3 2 1}} $fileContents]
```

Now, it's often a good idea to define a separate command for `updateInPlace` to call, and if the processing is complex (more than one command, basically) you need to do so. But in this case you're only performing one simple action. The beauty of Tcl syntax is that commands easily can be assembled. If you give `updateInPlace` half of a command, it will complete the command by adding the file's contents to it, execute the command and replace the file's contents with the result.

Let's say you have a file containing only the string `foo bar`. If you wanted to 1) print that out and 2) clear the file's contents, you could invoke

```
fileutil::updateInPlace test.txt puts
```

The `updateInPlace` command would read the file's contents and append it to the word `puts`, with a space in between, yielding the invocation `puts {foo bar}`. The string would be printed, and the result, which is the empty string, would be written back to the file, replacing the earlier contents.

The half-of-a-command you provide can have further arguments, as long as the file's contents will fit in as a last argument. For instance you could copy the contents somewhere else, to another open file or through a socket:

```
fileutil::updateInPlace test.txt "puts $channel"
```

sends the contents to wherever the channel identifier `$channel` is connected.

You can probably guess where I'm going with this.

```
fileutil::updateInPlace test.txt {string map {{1 2 3} {3 2 1}}}
```

is all you need to perform the processing you wanted.

If you want to be able to easily change the pattern to match and still substitute it with its reverse, you can do this:

```
set pattern {1 2 3}
fileutil::updateInPlace test.txt [list string map [list $pattern [lreverse $pattern]]]
```

---

Aside: when do you quote your command with braces, when should you use double quotes, and why use the `list` command?

In brief: if you need to substitute anything inside the command string, you use quotes or `list`. If you don't, you can use braces. If you need to make substitutions but also preserve list structure, you have to use `list`. So:

```
puts              ;# one word: you don't need to use any of the above
{puts}            ;# but any one of them will do
{puts -nonewline} ;# two words: you need to wrap it: any method will do
"puts $f"         ;# two words, need to substitute: quotes or list will do
```

You can check what your command will look like by printing it:

```
puts "string map {$pattern [lreverse $pattern]}"
# => string map {1 2 3 3 2 1}
```

Here the necessary list structure is lost. Fail. (That's what I wrote earlier.)

```
puts [list string map [list $pattern [lreverse $pattern]]]
# => string map {{1 2 3} {3 2 1}}
```

The list structure is preserved. Score! (Fixed by Donal Fellows.)

---

Doing it without `fileutil` (and without error handling):

```
set f [open test.txt r]
set fileContents [chan read -nonewline $f]
chan close $f
set f [open test.txt w]
chan puts -nonewline $f [string map {{1 2 3} {3 2 1}} $fileContents]
chan close $f
```

This version is a lot longer since the operations are more basic. This script opens the file twice: once for reading, putting the contents into the varible `fileContents`, and once for writing, putting the transformed contents back into the file.

A little less verbose:

```
set f [open test.txt r+]
chan puts -nonewline $f [string map {{1 2 3} {3 2 1}} [chan read -nonewline $f][chan seek $f 0;list]]
chan close $f
```

This version opens the file both for reading and writing. The contents are never stored in any variable but piped directly from the `chan read` through the `string map` to the `chan puts` which writes the transformed contents back into the file. (The `chan seek $f 0;list` bit is a trick to sneak in a necessary resetting of the writing position to the beginning of the file.)

---

Documentation: [chan](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/chan.htm), [fileutil](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/fileutil.html), [list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm), [open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm), [package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [return](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

Comment: @DonalFellows: thank you for fixing the bug, I must have nodded off there. I could have sworn I tested all snippets, but I obviously missed that one.

Comment: :thank you for the elaborated reply . The requirement is not to replace a list with it's reverse, but : parse a file, identify a pattern (DATA)  and replace the third element from the list. Moreover , the change needs to be persistent for every DAT inside the file. How can I achieve this behavior?